# Sorting by a slice of the text string

Tags: r, string, excel, sorting

I am wanting to sort my data but the standard Excel "A to Z" sort function isn't cutting it. I was hoping someone knew how to make a custom sort that could suit my needs. Here is a sample:

```
chrPos        count
chr1_10000598   10
chr1_10000647   10
chr1_10001370   30
chr1_10001390   30
chr1_10001392   30
chr1_10001414   30
chr1_10001418   30
chr1_10001473   10
chr1_10001505   10
chr1_10001516   20
chr1_1000156    30
```

As you can see the last row is out of place when using the built in sort function, this should be the first row not the last one here. I think adding a second layer of sorting would to the trick but that layer would have to sort by ascending value based on the number that is following the underscore.

Any ideas? Would this possibly be easier with R instead?

*Edit to add details from comments:*

Sorting is to be ascending on the numeric part after the underscore, within ascending on the chr numeric part (running from 1 to 22 both inclusive) and then chrM_, chrX_ and chrY_ in that order (also with their numeric parts sorted ascending).

The numeric part after the underscore may be up to 8 digits.

Comment: Oops sorry I meant first, not third. Basically ascending value after the underscore. The thing I forgot to mention is the chr# isn't constant... i.e. this list goes from chr1 to chr22 it is bio data.

Comment: Yeah didn't sleep much sorry haha.. I would like it sorted first by the chr# then by the number following the underscore.

Comment: My logic being; since this is a genomic position I would like it sorted linearly as a genome would be from start to finish... starting at chr1_1 and finishing at chr22_99999999, for example. If that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `chrPos` is in ColumnA, please try in a helper column:

```
=IF(FIND("_",A1)=5,CHAR(64+MID(A1,4,1)),CHAR(64+MID(A1,4,2)))&REPT("0",8-LEN(A1)+FIND("_",A1))&MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,8)
```

OR, for additional requirements as mentioned in comments:

```
=IF(MID(A1,4,1)="M","W",IF(MID(A1,4,1)="X","X",IF(MID(A1,4,1)="Y","Y",IF(FIND("_",A1)=5,CHAR(64+MID(A1,4,1)),CHAR(64+MID(A1,4,2))))))&REPT("0",9-LEN(A1)+FIND("_",A1))&MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,9)
```

then select the helper column, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and use that for sorting.

Comment: Hi thanks, this is very close! It works fine for all instances when there are 8 numbers after the underscore, but errors when there is 9 numbers afters the underscore. Sorry I didn't show any instances of 9 numbers in what I posted but it is in my data set. Also there is an error in the 3 instances if chrM, chrX, and chrY. Thanks again for the help I would never be able to do this...

Comment: My apologies. There is chr1 through chr22 and chrM, chrY, and chrX. Then there is up to a 9 character number following the underscore. Here are some screenshots that capture both of these error instances: http://imgur.com/SnCddcD,MnGq4ok

Comment: Before or after chr1 through chr21, either is fine.

Comment: After chr21, that was a typo. So for example the order would go chr1_#-chr22_#,chrM_#,chrY_#,chrX_#. Where the # would also be sorted ascendingly from 1 to 999999999 (nine digits).